# Make images inline and username with level beneath them

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="players">
    {{#each users}}
        {{#each usersInLobby}}
        <img src="/img/chars/{{skin}}.png" style="height: 85px">
            <p>{{username}}{{level}}</p>
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

This is my code currently. But its displayed like that:

[image]

I want to make usernames below the images and images display inline.

Comment: Try loocking into flex: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/  this will also help you in the future

Comment: Could you please post your generated HTML content not your template code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you want. Here are two examples:

**Using `display: inline-block;`**

```css
.player {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="players">
    <div class="player">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
        <p>Username - Level</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="player">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
        <p>Username - Level</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Using `display: flex;`**

```css
.players {
  display: flex;
}

.player {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="players">
    <div class="player">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
        <p>Username - Level</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="player">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100">
        <p>Username - Level</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Both solutions need you to wrap your elements inside a wrapping `div`.

Answer (score 0):

By "inline" I suppose you mean centered? Try:

```html
<div class="players">
                {{#each users}}
                    {{#each usersInLobby}}
                    <img src="/img/chars/{{skin}}.png" style="height: 85px; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px;">
                        <p>{{username}}{{level}}</p>
                    {{/each}}
                {{/each}}
            </div>
```

Comment: No. I mean images in line and text below them

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the `img` and `p` in a `div` then apply `inline-block` on the `div`:

```
        <div class="players">
             {{#each users}}
                {{#each usersInLobby}}
                     <div class="users">
                       <img src="/img/chars/{{skin}}.png" style="height: 85px">
                       <p>{{username}}{{level}}</p>
                     </div>
                {{/each}}
            {{/each}}
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.users{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```